# Как заставить работать animation-delay последовательно?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Добрый день, коллеги.

У меня вопрос по установке последовательного воспроизведения анимации у блоков

САБЖ:

Есть несколько дивов, у которых должна ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, с задержкой работать анимация. Анимация идет бесконечным циклом.
Т.е. сначала должна отыграть анимашка в первом блоке, потом во-втором, потом, в третьем, потом все по кругу. С задержкой в пару секунд у каждого блока.

ПРОБЛЕМА:

Задержка отрабатывает только при первом проигрывании.

Что я делаю не так?

Здесь уже были ответы на подобные вопросы, но я как-то не нашла ничего вразумительного. Если у вас есть ссылка - прошу, дайте.

Заранее БЛАГОДАРЮ за помощь!

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 30px);
          flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 30px);
  background: url("http://popwebfun.com/for/bi/in/gcb_lottery/distr/images/bg_cell.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  /*ratio*/
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -120%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.25);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg);
          transform: skewX(35deg);
  -webkit-animation: glanse 2s linear infinite;
          animation: glanse 2s linear infinite;
}
.box-1:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-2:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}
.box-3:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glanse {
  0% {
    left: -120%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 120%;
  }
}

@keyframes glanse {
  0% {
    left: -120%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2"></div>
  <div class="box box-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем, дорогие коллеги, вся соль в пропроции длительности анимации, задержкой и временной функции. [Поиграть тут](https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/PRqrwR)

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 30px);
          flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 30px);
  background: url("http://popwebfun.com/for/bi/in/gcb_lottery/distr/images/bg_cell.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  /*ratio*/
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -120%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.25);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg);
          transform: skewX(35deg);
  -webkit-animation: glanse 2s linear infinite;
          animation: glanse 2s linear infinite;
}
.box-1:after {
 -webkit-animation: glanse 2s 0.0s ease-in infinite;
          animation: glanse 2s 0.0s ease-in infinite;
}
.box-2:after {
 -webkit-animation: glanse 2s 1.5s ease-in infinite;
          animation: glanse 2s 1.5s ease-in infinite;
}
.box-3:after {
 -webkit-animation: glanse 2s 2.0s ease-in infinite;
          animation: glanse 2s 2.0s ease-in infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glanse {
  0% {
    left: -120%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 120%;
  }
}

@keyframes glanse {
  0% {
    left: -120%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2"></div>
  <div class="box box-3"></div>
</div>
```